# Combo Box in Access 2007 Report

Tags: ms-access-2007

How do you put a combo box in an Access 2007 Report so you can select a record ID and it will bring up the record in the report so it can be printed?

Comment: You don't. Reports are for display and printing, and have no UI. As @Remou suggests, you would need to create a UI object to do this, either a form as he suggests or a toolbar button or menu item. The form is much easier than the latter two, which would require a function to be called from the toolbar/menu item.

Answer (score 0):

What you would normally do is create a small form that can be used to open the report. In Access 2007, you can take advantage of the Where argument of the OpenReport method.

[DoCmd.OpenReport Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238032.aspx)

On the form you might have a button with some code:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "TheReport", , , "NumericID=" & Me.ComboBox
```